# Pass over ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, exception, classloader

I have a static initialization block and from it is thrown an `ExceptionInInitializerError` Exception. 
Is there any way to pass over this exception and to access the other fields and methods from this class?
Thank you.

Comment: What is wrong in that block?

Comment: I know what is wrong, and it is ok to be wrong, but I just want to know if there is a way (hopefully not) to recover from this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the call to initiate the class which contains the static block into try block and catch `ExceptionInInitializerError`. Like the following:

```
try{
    ClassWithStaticBlock cb = new ClassWithStaticBlock();
}
    catch(ExceptionInInitializerError ex){      
}
```

Comment: One does simply not catch a ExceptionInInitializerError.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason behind the [ExceptionInInitializerError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html) is that, when the JVM come across the unexpected situation that can not be handled the JVM will throw the above error. `ExceptionInInitializerError` can be caught, though you shouldn't catch [Error](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html), it is actually impossible to recover from it, because the class in which the exception occurred is made unavailable for further use (such as instantiating the class), yielding a `NoClassDefFoundError.`You can refer to [JLS - Detailed Initialization Procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2).